# Selective refresh and registering widget areas

Tags: theme-customizer

I've a select drop down control in the customizer that controls which header template is rendered. This currently works via a full page refresh.

Different header templates include a different set of widget areas. This isn't a problem when using the refresh transport method as the correct widget areas for the selected header always get registered correctly (via `widgets_init` hook) during a normal page load.

However, I want to switch to using selective refresh for header templates. The actual rendering of the header using partials isn't an issue, but I need to be able to dynamically register the correct widget areas depending on the selected header template now that I'm not doing a full page refresh.

Any ideas on how this could be approached?